# Strict Mode "A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released" exception with Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-strictmode, strict-mode

Im getting the following exception on strict mode when starting my app. Just after my login activity is closed and right before my main activity, which contains a SupportMapFragment, is displayed.

> 10-29 16:11:22.605: E/StrictMode(1121): A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
>   10-29 16:11:22.605: E/StrictMode(1121): java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
>   10-29 16:11:22.605: E/StrictMode(1121):   at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
>   10-29 16:11:22.605: E/StrictMode(1121):   at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<*init*>(RandomAccessFile.java:128)
>   10-29 16:11:22.605: E/StrictMode(1121):   at maps.d.a.<*init*>(Unknown Source)
>   10-29 16:11:22.605: E/StrictMode(1121):   at maps.d.b.a(Unknown Source)
>   10-29 16:11:22.605: E/StrictMode(1121):   at maps.m.h.a(Unknown Source)
>   10-29 16:11:22.605: E/StrictMode(1121):   at maps.m.a.a(Unknown Source)
>   10-29 16:11:22.605: E/StrictMode(1121):   at maps.m.u.a(Unknown Source)
>   10-29 16:11:22.605: E/StrictMode(1121):   at maps.k.n.c(Unknown Source)
>   10-29 16:11:22.605: E/StrictMode(1121):   at maps.ao.b.run(Unknown Source)
>   10-29 16:11:22.605: W/System.err(1121): StrictMode VmPolicy violation with POLICY_DEATH; shutting down.

Its seems related to GoogleMap on the main activity. but what exactly needs to be closed there ? Any thought/idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

add this method:

```
public static void enableStrictMode(Context context) {
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(
    new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
    .detectDiskReads()
    .detectDiskWrites()
    .detectNetwork()
    .penaltyLog()
    .build());
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(
    new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
    .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()
    .penaltyLog()
    .build());
    }
```

and `enableStrictMode(this);` before `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` in onCreate. In my problem this solution help.

Comment: StrictMode job is to flush these issues out. How does a change to StrictMode configuration as a solution make sense here  ?

Comment: @AsafK Are you finding too many errors in your code? Just stop looking. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Stacktrace shows only code from Google Maps Android API v2, so you will not be able to do much about the root cause of it.

I suggest posting a issue on [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype=Android2) with this bug.

In the meantime disable this kind of check in strict mode.

Comment: Posted - https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5992&thanks=5992&ts=1383090620. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when i tried to run my app. The fix was simple: i just had to have internet  activated on my phone. Maybe you should have all the resources that your phone is using(eg. GPS, internet) activated when you run the app.